# How to draw perfect rectangle using paths tool in GIMP?

Tags: gimp

I want to draw rectangle (perpendicular edges) using paths tool. I tried using grid, but it does not give precision.
Also tried "snap to grid" option seems to not work with Paths tool.

In pencil tool, if I select `ctrl` + `shift` while drawing line, I'm able to achieve this functionality. Is there any similar way for paths tool?

Thanks for you time.

Comment: Would using the Rectangle Select tool work for you? You can then click Select > To Path - which converts the rectangle selection to a path.

Comment: Which version? Snap to grid seems to work for me in 2.8.20 / Win.

Comment: Snap to grid also works with the Paths Tool in GIMP 2.10.2 on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Typically you would use guides. Possible technique:

1. position two guides that intersect in a corner.
2. Using the Measure tool, drag a diagonal to the opposite corner, looking at the measures/coordinate in the status area.
3. At the right spot, depress Alt+Ctrl and re-click, this will create H and V guides on that point.
4. Create your path using the guides.